# Output response details via loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I submit some data via jQuery .ajax() and receive some data back via response. I need to output the data on my page. For example this is one of the responses I get:

```
{ 
  "res": 1, 
  "item": [
      {"id":"1","desc":"blue box","rating":"1"},
      {"id":"2","desc":"red ball","rating":"5"}
  ] 
}
```

I output this response via a loop like this:

```
...
success: function (response) {

    for (var i = 0; i < response.item.length; i++){
         var item = response.item[i].id,
             desc = response.item[i].desc,
             rate = response.item[i].rating;

         $('#em' + response.res).append(item+'. '+ desc + ' Rating:' + rate);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately what I get is two rows of the same item. What am I missing?

Comment: What does your html look like? Do you have an element with the id `em1`?

Comment: Yes, I do long polling for different elements that meet certain criteria, and return response for those elements.

Comment: Well it works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uxun0p81/) so the problem is somewhere else that you aren't showing us.

Comment: Yes, went through my code a number of times, it all looks fine. Maybe some weird caching going on?..

Comment: Then look at the network response and see if you are getting the data you expect. There is nothing obviously wrong with the code you have shared, so I don't know if anybody is going to be able to help without more information.

Comment: Response returns two different data sets. However, I noticed that I append the last one twice. So after poking more I noticed that .append happen withing setTimeout(), instead of adding the entire loop withing it. My mistake... got it! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your not closing your for loop.

```
success: function (response) {

    for (var i = 0; i < response.item.length; i++){
         var item = response.item[i].id,
             desc = response.item[i].desc,
             rate = response.item[i].rating;         
         $('#em' + response.res).append(item + '. ' + desc + ' Rating:' + rate);
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I did not close it here in the example code. I just checked my actual code and everything is closed. But I close it after I append data.

Comment: @santa Also, note that `item+` is incorrect syntax for your variable, use `item + '`. `'+ desc`  is also wrong syntax. `' + desc` is correct.Try this `.append(item + '. ' + desc + ' Rating:' + rate);`

Comment: @JoshSpears: `item+` and `item +` makes absolutely no difference.

Comment: @MattBurland Didn't know that. Good to know. Thanks